# gdb and current function stack

Tags: gdb, stack

so I know that my current block is between epb and esp
is there a way to print my stack the following way:
lets says that len=ebp-esp
I would like a command on gdb that would look like this
x/lenx $esp

so I'm priting what's on the stack for the current function being executed?
can I do this using display like:
display/lenx $esp ?

Comment: Yes, you can. For example: display 10 words:`display /10wx $esp` or for example display 40 bytes: `display /40bx $esp`.

Comment: yes I know about that way, my question was is it possible to have a variable that will change each time (that would be len = $ebp-$esp).
so when esp change, the display will calculate the new value of len and show what's on my stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to have a variable that will change each time

Seems `display` doesn't allow this. So you can define your own command and simply call it when you need to see a function stack:

```
define display_stack
  eval "x /%dbx $esp", $ebp-$esp
end
```

And then while debugging your program:

```
(gdb) display_stack
```

If you need to see your function stack on each step you can 1) define another command `nn` and use it when you debug your functions 2) use hook for the pseudo-command, ‘stop’ :

```
define nn
  n
  display_stack
end

define hook-stop
  echo "hook-stop, display_stack:\n"
  display_stack
end
```

Useful links:

- http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html
- http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output.html#index-eval-1736
- http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html